# Must a webpage end in ".php" in order to run php code?

Tags: php, html

Does a webpage need to end in ".php" in order to run php code?  Is there a way a file ending in ".html" can run php code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using the Apache web server you can add this line to its configuration:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

it tells the the server that files with a `.html` extension have to be considered as PHP files. I don't recommend this though, as it forces the PHP engine on every file (even static html pages).

Alternatively you can rewrite (some) `.html` URLs to their PHP version via `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: good point on forcing the PHP engine- prob not a worthwhile endeavor- thanks--

Answer (score 9):

No a webpage doesn't need to end in `.php` to be parsed as PHP.

Yes you can use any extension you want depending on your web server, for example the below code placed in the Apache configuration would parse files with a `.htm`, `.html` or `.php` extension as PHP if running on an Apache server.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html .php
```

And you may also try this with regular expressions to better match specific criteria:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: +1 for bringing regular expressions into the midst of the conversation

Comment: can i put this inside `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 3):

You can have PHP parse any file type, as long as you tell it to.

In .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

This tells PHP to parse .php and .html files.

Answer (score 2):

You could also eliminate the extension altogether with this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

So now
http://www.test.com/mypage.php
will be http://www.test.com/mypage

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into URL Rewriting instead of messing up the .html configuration in Apache. This way you can have php pages end in anything you want or even not have any extension at all. Extensionless SEO friendly URLs are always better than any existing filenames with extension.

Just my 2 coins :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way: associate the .html extension with PHP in the Apache/other webserver config.

However, it's not recommended to make PHP pages look like HTML, it's better to crop the extension as is.

Comment: "not recommended to make PHP pages look like HTML"- why not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The change you make to your .htaccess file can vary by host.

On mediatemple, for example, you add this ::

```
SetHandler php-script
```

[See mediatemple documentation on this topic here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/145/%28gs%29+Using+SetHandler+to+process+other+extensions+as+PHP#gs)